# ftp_put(): Command STOR failed

Tags: php, laravel, ftp

In my Laravel application I'm trying to allow the user to upload basic files to a remote FTP and I've been able to create a connection to my FTP through PHP but the moment my code hits the ftp_put() it throws this error.

```
ftp_put(): Command STOR failed
```

I've verified that I am able to upload files to my FTP through FileZilla and it does let me do that. Any sort of insight would be awesome.

And below is the code I am using at the moment.

```
if (Input::hasFile('file')) {
        $path = Input::file('file')->getRealPath();

        $uploadpath = '/users/';

        $usr = 'login';
        $pwd = 'password';

        // file to move:
        $local_file = $path;
        $ftp_path = $uploadpath;

        // connect to FTP server
        $conn_id = ftp_connect('ftp.url.com');

        // send access parameters
        ftp_login($conn_id, $usr, $pwd);

        // turn on passive mode transfers (some servers need this)
        ftp_pasv ($conn_id, true);

        // perform file upload
        ftp_put($conn_id, $ftp_path, $local_file, FTP_ASCII);

        ftp_close($conn_id);
    }
```

Comment: The account I'm using seems to just have permissions on this specific folder, as in if I try to go up to the root it restricts my access.

Could it be that when it tries the `ftp_put()` it sees it can't access root to get further into the directory and throws the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution!

My upload path was just the path itself, after I made an appends to the upload path to include the file name as well it let the upload through.

So if anyone happens upon this same issue in the same circumstances:

```
 $uploadpath = '/users/' . $file_name;
 $ftp_path = $uploadpath;
```